# Serve static file from /

Tags: node.js, express

If I define

```
app.use('/*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../pub/index.html')));
```

Then it appears that I need to provide at least one character after / in my url to get index.html.
If I define the route with just `/`, I get 404 for anything in the browser.

How do I get a default file served up with just `/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [serve-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static):

```
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, '../pub'), {'index' ['index.html']}));
```

It should serve the *index.html*, which is located in *../pub*, if you call e.g. `localhost:3000`.